# Creating a user table in Qt

Tags: c++, sql, database, qt

I want to add to my project a possibility of a user creating his own table, where he/she could choose the number of columns, add their name and choose the type for each column. The idea is, that value of a number is got from lineEdit, names as well and type from a comboBox. How can I do it in QtCreator using c++?

I'm really new in that, so, I'm open to any option and I'd like to have a direct answer with an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want create a table with "QTableWidget" you can make this with

```
QTableWidget tableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
tableWidget->setColumnCount( numberCols );
```

now you can set header of columns with:

```
tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(m_tableHeader);
```

where tableHeader is a array of titles.

Comment: So, headers will be added like this: id, name, class ? and how to identify their relations with the other tables I have?

Comment: if you have to create relationships with the tables already existed I would opt for two options:
- the table identifier is always present and is the first column of the table created;
- created the table you could select the column to use as foreign key and the table / column to make the relationship

Comment: Ohh, so, the table is created -> set the connections after? That sounds great!